# how to Read a text file until certain character in php

Tags: php, text, character

Is there any way to select a part of a text file until a certain word?
for example we have the text below:

```
hello my name is Ehsan i'm from iran 
<hr>
I'm 20 years old and ...
```

I want to select from hello until `<hr>` an save it to another file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Use `file_get_content()` to read file content to string, then select  desired string using `strstr()` and finally put your selected string using `file_put_content()` to another file ;

Comment: i want select a part of the text file like above example

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP's explode function to split the string (str_split has been deprecated) - it's pretty useful:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
  <?php
       //String we want to split
       $string = 'Hello<hr />World';

       //Splits the string into an array of strings delimited by <hr />
       $newString = explode('<hr />', $string);

       //So by that logic the first element at index 0 will be Hello
       //The second element will be at index 1 and will be World

       //So let's write the first element, up until <hr /> to the file
       file_put_contents('hello.txt', $newString[0]);

       //Note: $string still contains the original string
  ?>
```

So explode() takes param 1 as a delimiter, and param 2 as the string and transforms this into an array of strings split at the given point.

Enjoy! :)

Comment: it doesn't work true in the above exmple if you write hello Instead Hello it return ello and also it doesnt attention to certain char.

Comment: Could be write permissions in the folder preventing the file being created. You can try changing the first parameter of file_put_contents to a location that you know you have write permissions for :-)

Comment: I've update my solution - apologies I got the question a bit muddled :)